# How to replace characters in a string while looping?

Tags: c#, string, loops, replace

I would like to verify if a file exists on multiple servers.  The only thing that's different on the servers is the number on the server, ex. Server1, Server2, Server3, etc.

*How would I write a loop that replaces each number with the next highest number up until, say Server 10?*

Here is what I have so far:

```
var fileLocation = @"\\Server1\documents\File.txt";
var newFileInfoTest = fileLocation.Replace("Server1", "Server2");

if (File.Exists(newFileInfoTest))
    txtTextBox.Text = "Server1 -- File copy successful.";
else
    txtTextBox.Text = "Server1 -- File copy unsuccessful";
```

Comment: There is no loop in your code example. Please provide the code you need help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"How would I write a loop that replaces each number with the next highest number up until, say Server 10?"*

You can set the server name in a loop, using the loop iterator value as part of the server name

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    txtTextBox.Text = File.Exists($@"\\Server{i}\documents\File.txt")
        ? $"Server{i} -- File copy successful."
        : $"Server{i} -- File copy unsuccessful";
}
```

Note that the code above will overwrite the `txtTextBox.Text` value on each iteration. You may instead want to capture all the statuses in the loop and then display them at the end:

```
txtTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => File.Exists($@"\\Server{i}\documents\File.txt")
        ? $"Server{i} -- File copy successful."
        : $"Server{i} -- File copy unsuccessful."));
```

---

In the comments you asked:

> *"How would you do this if the file location was in a variable?"*

One way to do this is to use a format string with a placeholder (`{0}`) where the number would go, and then use `string.Format` to fill in that placeholder inside the loop.

We can extract the server name from this string using `string.Split` on the `\` character and grabbing the first item.

For example:

```
var serverPath = @"\\Server{0}\documents\File.txt";

txtTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i =>
    {
        var thisPath = string.Format(serverPath, i);
        var serverName = thisPath.Split(new[] { '\\' },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
        return File.Exists(thisPath)
            ? $"{serverName} -- File copy successful."
            : $"{serverName} -- File copy unsuccessful.";
    }));
```

Comment: Actually, I did the same:)

Comment: Thanks @RufusL, this was what I was looking for.  How would you do this if the file location was in a variable?  Or would that be a different question to ask?

Comment: See my answer for the variable version.

Comment: I posted a sample that uses a variable to store the template for the server path, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, make sure your message will not get over write, you can use string builder instead of concatenation. hope you can get the logic

```
    var msg = string.Empty;
    for(int i = 1; i <  11; i++) { 
        var fileLocation = $"\\Server{i}\documents\File.txt";

         if (File.Exists(fileLocation))
         {
           msg += $"Server{i} -- File copy successful.";
         }
         else
         {
           msg += $"Server{i} -- File copy unsuccessful."; 
         }
    }

    txtTextBox.Text = msg;
```

Comment: @SQLPolice - Right, the first answer will be always in hurry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
 var fileLocation = $@"\\Server{i}\documents\File.txt";

 if (File.Exists(fileLocation))
    txtTextBox.Text = $"Server{i} -- File copy successful.";
 else
    txtTextBox.Text = $"Server{i} -- File copy unsuccessful";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "How would I write a loop that replaces each number with the next highest number up until, say Server 10?"

```
var numberofServers = 10;
for(int i =0; i <= numberOfServers; i++){
var fileLocation = $"\\Server{i}\\documents\\File.txt";

if(File.Exists(fileLocation)){
//Success
}    
else{
//UnSuccessful
}
}
```